# spring form:form data-binding inside c:forEach

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, data-binding

I would like to get some data-binding working the following way:

```
<c:forEach var="form" items="${forms}" varStatus="status">
  <form:form modelAttribute="form"> 
    <form:input path="key"/>
  </form:form>
</c:forEach>
```

But the problem is, I think that the model attribute can't be a dynamic reference or at least I don't know how to express that.

`forms` is a collection of objects which have an attribute `key`.

I found many other solutions, which for instance use the status variable like

```
<form:input path="${forms[status.index].key}"/>
```

but i need to reference "key" directly instead of this array access prefix.

any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<form:form modelAttribute="${form}"> 
    <form:input path="${form.key}"/>
</form:form>
```

Also, if you are using the `Map` collection then you can access the value using `${form.value}`.

In your code `<form:form modelAttribute="form">` express string `form` as `modelAttribute` name and not the actual value which you wish to bind as `modelAttribute`.

Comment: I already tried this, not working.
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'de' available as request attribute"

I think this is because the content of path needs to be an actual path with respect to the form's modelAttribute and not the value of key itself

Comment: It means you are not using this model attribute in your request handling methods. Also I don't get why you are trying to bind only one field for each form? If that is not your intention then move the `<form:form>` tag outside `<c:forEach>` tag.

Comment: the model IS being used. if i simply print the value as e.g. <p>${form.key}</p> inside of the forEach, it is correctly displayed.

Comment: Could you share your RequstHandling method which is using `de` modelAttribute?

Comment: And I cannot move the form one level up because i want to generate multiple forms, one form for each object in the list.
the single input form above was just a simple example in order to illustrate my problem

Comment: thats the strange thing, there is no "de" model attribute and it is not referenced anywhere. And the error is only thrown as soon as i add an input having a path attribute

Comment: @M. Lutz, whenever you are binding the modelAttribute in form tag, Spring will expect the modelAttribute to be used in your Controller for instance. That's why you are getting this exception.

Comment: yeah, but is it possbile to not feed the form by the controller's model but by a for each item?
otherwise, i will have to add each element of the list for instance as "form0", "form1", ...
which is not that elegant

Comment: Suppose, you have a `<form:form modelAttribute="de"> ` and a field inside it as `<form:input path="name"/>`, then Spring will expect that you have a bean object containing `name` field which is set into `ModelAttribute` when you display this  page.